# Principal eigenfunction as a solution on a subdomain

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations

I am looking for information on the following:

Suppose $u$ is a classical solution of,
\begin{align}
-\Delta u &=\lambda_{1}u\quad\text{in }\Omega\\
u&=0\quad\text{on }\partial\Omega
\end{align}
where $\lambda_{1}$ is the principal eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on $\Omega$ with homogeneous boundary conditions. We can assume $\Omega$ to be smooth and bounded. Now consider, $\Omega_{0}\subset\Omega$ to be a proper subdomain. Will there be appropriate boundary conditions for $u$ on $\partial\Omega_{0}$ such that,
\begin{align}
-\Delta u&=\lambda_{1}u\quad\text{in }\Omega_{0}\\
u&=g(x)\quad\text{on }\partial\Omega_{0}
\end{align}
and so one can consider $\lambda_{1}$ as the principal eigenvalue of $-\Delta$ on $\Omega_{0}$ with the new boundary conditions?

My intuition tells me that this should be possible since $u$ is continuous then $u|_{\partial\Omega_{0}}$ is well defined. So we can just take $g(x)$ to be the point-wise values of $u$ on $\partial\Omega_{0}$.

If anyone has any information regarding this idea can you please leave a source where I can find out more? Googling something like this to find sources isn't easy.

Comment: If one imposes a non-zero boundary condition, then $u$ cannot be an eigenfunction. The problem ceases to be linear, i.e. solutions do not form a vector space.

Comment: @Chrystomath sorry can you explain that a little more? I think I see what you are saying, that since the solutions do not form a subspace then the operator never fails to be bijective?

Comment: Not bijectivity. You don't even get a vector space of solutions. $\lambda u$ does not sayisfy the boundary conditions.

Comment: @Chrystomath Do we not have a notion of eigenvalues/eigenfunctions for nonlinear problems? Also I understand the problem is non-linear, but the differential operator is still linear no? Does this not account for something?

Comment: @Chrystomath Also could one think of the problem on the subdomain with inhomogeneous Neumann BC's?

Comment: Eigenfunctions can be arbitrarily large, hence they are associated with resonance. $\triangle$ on $\Omega_0$ is still linear of course, but you have to associate linear, i.e. *homogeneous*, boundary conditions, to speak about eigenvalues. The whole point of eigenvectors is to be able to write solutions as a sum of them, hence the necessity of linearity.

Comment: @Chrystomath Ok that makes sense. I can't expand other solutions as a linear combination of anything in the problem on $\Omega_{0}$. So all I really have here is the existence of $\textbf{a}$ solution $u$.